# JS - How to define multi status property on object

Tags: javascript, interface

I have this interface created on Angular in order to "shape" the object between the front and the server.

```
export interface RepairNote{
  id: number,
  nombre?: string,
  telefono?: number,
  ref?: string
  marca?: string,
  averia?: string,
  fecha?: Date,
  estado?: /* here */
}
```

I'm willing to have "estado" (English: status) with a different closed group of status, being "Pending, Complete and Closed". Meaning that estado can only have one of these 3 values. In my mind it works like a boolean, but with more than 2 status. This is a very simple question, I know it belongs to the basics of OOP, but I got blank and I don't know how to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use "enum" for these sort of things:

```
export enum Status {
  Pending = 'Pending',
  Complete = 'Complete',
  Closed = 'Closed',
}

export interface RepairNote {
  // ...
  status?: Status;
  // ...
}
```

Here you can find more information about enums: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html

Comment: Thank you. Does this way "force" to have one of the definitions inside enum? Would error if another thing is written for its value?

Comment: I'm now in the backend and it is not ts, but js, so I dont know what type to set on the model. I put type: {}, as there is no "enum". Any suggestions?

Comment: If you stick to TypeScript both on the Frontend and the Backend it would prevent it from such value to be settable in the code. One additional layer of security you could add on the backend is to run all the models received from the client through a JSON schema validator, for example this one: https://ajv.js.org/